# The current value is the maximum value in the most recent period

Tags: pandas, numpy

l = [5,1,1,1,5,3,6], and the expected returned data is [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, **0**, 6]. Compare from right to left, if it is greater than, it will count cumulatively; if it is less than or equal to, it will **interrupt** the accumulation and start the next counting.

How to implement (**numpy,pandas**)?

```
pandas:
def TOPRANGE(S):
    rt = np.zeros(len(S))
    for i in range(1,len(S)):  rt[i] = np.argmin(np.flipud(S[:i]<S[i]))
    return rt.astype('int')

l = [5,1,1,1,5,3,6]
s = np.array(l)
TOPRANGE(s)

output: [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0]
expected returned data is [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 6],Don't know how to solve it????
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l = [5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 3, 6]
# l = [5, 1, 3, 6]

l.reverse(); out = []
for i in range(0,len(l)):
    acc = 0
    for j in range(i+1, len(l)):
        if l[i] > l[j]: acc += 1
        else: break   # interrupt count
    out.append(acc)
out.reverse(); out
```

Gives required output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 6]
```

Comment: How to implement (numpy,pandas)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well the logic, this looks like an expanding comparison:

pure python

```
l = [5,1,3,6]
out = [sum(l[i]>x for x in l[:i]) for i in range(len(l))]
```

pandas

```
l = [5,1,3,6]
s = pd.Series(l)

out = s.expanding().apply(lambda x: sum(x.iloc[:-1].le(x.iloc[-1]))).astype(int)
out.tolist()
```

numpy:

```
l = [5,1,3,6]
a = np.array(l)

out = np.tril(a[:,None]>a).sum(1)
out.tolist()
```

output: `[0, 0, 1, 3]`

Comment: Compare from right to left, if it is greater than, it will count cumulatively; if it is less than or equal to, it will interrupt the accumulation and start the next counting.